# How do i make one button content close when i click another button's content in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that I have a website, using javascript I have made it when I click on the About Me it opens, but when I click on Education and Achievements the About me button's content remains open and the Education stuff overlaps it. I want to make it so that when I click on another button the first one closes (its content. The website name is dirieahmed.ml

My code HTML and JS will be linked below ill add CSS later if need be.

```
<div class="container">
  <button id="one" class="click one">About Me</button>
  <div class="list-1 sec">
    <h1 class="content-header-one content">Dummy text header</h1>
    <p class="content-paragraph-one">Dummy text</p>
  </div>
  <button class="click two">Education and Achivements</button>
  <div class="list-2 sec">
    <p class="content-paragraph2 content">Dummy text</p>
    <ul class="content-list content">
      <li>- Achivement #1</li>
      <li>- Achivement #2</li>
      <li>- Achivement #3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="click three" >Other</button>
  <div class="list-3 sec">
    <h1 class="content-header-two content">Dummy text header</h1>
    <p class="content-paragraph3 content">Dummy text</p>
  </div>
  <script async>
    let one = document.querySelector('.one');
    let two = document.querySelector('.two');
    let three = document.querySelector('.three');
    let list1 = document.querySelector('.list-1');
    let list2 = document.querySelector('.list-2');
    let list3 = document.querySelector('.list-3');
      one.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        list1.classList.toggle('newlist');  
    });
    two.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        list2.classList.toggle('newlist');
        lis
    })
    three.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        list3.classList.toggle('newlist')
    });
 
    // please change above
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize you will need to hide all other ones when there is a click anywhere and then only show the ones based on the link that you clicked

Check the code below

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-driscoll-igzlwb?file=/index.html:2333-3356

```
     <script async>
        // Instanciate List div's
        let list1 = document.querySelector(".list-1");
        let list2 = document.querySelector(".list-2");
        let list3 = document.querySelector(".list-3");

        // Reset's all views to the default without .newlist
        const resetAllViews = () => {
          list1.classList.remove("newlist");
          list2.classList.remove("newlist");
          list3.classList.remove("newlist");
        };

        // Checks to see what button is clicked and shows correct list based on input
      document.addEventListener(
        "click",
        function (e) {
          e = e || window.event;
          var target = e.target;
          if (target.classList.contains("one")) {
            resetAllViews();
            list1.classList.add("newlist");
          }
          if (target.classList.contains("two")) {
            resetAllViews();
            list2.classList.add("newlist");
          }
          if (target.classList.contains("three")) {
            resetAllViews();
            list3.classList.add("newlist");
          }
        }, false);

      </script>
```

Comment: i am kinda new to this stuff can you assist me further maybe in a easier manner or like how to incorporate this

Comment: Basically what you are trying to do here is make a page manager with a navigation bar that does not change, this task would be much easier using a framework like React.js as this is a built in feature. How many pages are you going to have for this website?

Comment: I update the above answer, that should work for you

Comment: so if i replace my JS with this it should work

Comment: btw only one for how many

Comment: You would still need to define list1, 2, and 3

Comment: So don't remove all of your code, and instead of toggling them I would do actually mutate the css properties to make this work, if you setup a code sandbox I will help you do it

Comment: it has made it so that all of them show and leave in randomized orders and when I click offscreen they all appear

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hellman-pyej06?file=/index.html @Will 40

Comment: I updated the answer, the code sandbox I sent back works. Please upvote if you are satisfied with the answer! Thank you

Comment: is there a way if i click on them again like About Me to close like if i click Education then About me then again About me to close all

Comment: inside of if(target.classList.contains("one")) you would have to add another if else statement that says if (list1.classList.contains("newlist") then remove it else add it

Comment: is it possible you can incorporate what u just said in ur answer

Comment: If i click on About me then Education then About me then About me AGAIN that it closes

Answer (score 0):

The **document** object should be given a **click** event listener.
Use the **contains()** function to determine with each click if the clicked element is outside the targeted element.
Hide the original element if the clicked element is outside.